# Display non-printable parameters in running processes

Tags: shell, ps, printf, ascii

`ps aux` displays commands running on the server, but it does not display non-printable parameters in any sort of way that is useful.

mycmd.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
        sleep 5
done
```

Executing it:

```
/mycmd.sh `printf "\x90\x90\x90"`
```

Will give:

```
> ps aux
/bin/bash ./mycmd.sh ???
```

Is there a way to list the actual command that is running? Including the non-printable characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pstree` which shows the args, eg for pid 18592:

```
$ pstree -a 18592
bash /tmp/mycmd.sh \220\220\220
```

or you can look directly in `/proc` for the process:

```
$ cat -v /proc/18592/cmdline | sed  's/\^@/ /g;s/$/\n/'
bash /tmp/mycmd.sh M-^PM-^PM-^P
```